# CSV function to pull selected columns from CSV object

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a function to pull columns from a csv file, the first time I run the function it works however every time after that I get an empty list.

First time posting so if I've made any mistakes please let me know.

I've posted my code below, if anyone has any ideas why it's not working I'd very much appreciate any suggestions.

'''

```
def listSelector(listObject, columnSelector): #Function to pull list from csv File
        listData = [] #initialise list

    for csvRow in listObject: #for loop loops through csv file object
        print(csvRow[columnSelector])
        listData.append(csvRow[columnSelector]) #Each loop data from CSV gets added to list

    return listData #return output list

import csv #import csv library         

csvFile = open('test.csv') #open function returns file object
csvObject = csv.reader(csvFile) #reader module generates csv object containting data


businessNames = listSelector(csvObject,0) #run function to pull selected colum from csv file
loanStartDate = listSelector(csvObject,1) #run function to pull selected colum from csv file


print(businessNames)
print(loanStartDate)

csvFile.close()
```

'''

[CSV test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmAQj.png)

Comment: Can you please post a few rows from test.csv?

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. I posted an image of it, not sure how to attach the actual file, if that's not enough let me know. Thanks

Comment: output from the script?

Comment: I get the first list correct, which is this ['Business', 'Business 1', 'Business 2', 'Business 3', 'Business 4', 'Business 5', 'Business 6', 'Business 7', 'Business 8', 'Business 9', 'Business 10'] But the next list is just empty where as it should be another column from the csv file.
[]

Comment: If I change the csvObject to a 2d list ie with csvList = list(csvObject) it works but not as an object.